# I have an angular app with a Node server - no DB yet. How to deploy on AWS?

Tags: node.js, angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I'm not sure where and how to start with AWS for deploying, very confused at the moment. It seems like I deploy my server on Elastic Beanstalk, but then where does my build and static files go? S3 I'm guessing? Should I just follow the tutorial for Beanstalk? Thanks!

Comment: deploy it to azure :D https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-web-get-started-nodejs

Answer (score 1):

You can use Elastic Beanstalk to host your entire application including Static files where it will resides in the web server.

The downside of it is the performance for large scale applications where you can leverage AWS S3 and CloudFront. So if you are a starter with AWS, then I would recommend to consider Elastic Beanstalk for entire application hosting for the moment.

Comment: No probs. If you think the answer is directly applicable, you can click "Accept Answer Sign" it so that others can also refer. Thanks!